# Build specific conditional symbols in Windows 8 Metro Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In C++ and C# applications one can define conditional compilation symbols, such as DEBUG, TRACE or RELEASE and use these in program code to enable/disable code generation with #if.

I need to do similar thing in a Windows 8 Metro Javascript application: have different builds (Debug/Release) behave slightly differently. Is this supported somehow?

Answer (score 1):

In the Windows 8 Developer Preview, Visual Studio for Metro Style JavaScript applications there is no pre-processing of JavaScriot nor is there a compilation step. However, you can via MSBuild plug in your own pre-processor (or reuse the C one). You can just edit the .wwaproj file and add  target that invokes your pre-processor.

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
```

There are a couple of good articles* online for doing a similar thing with minifying JavaScript in Visual Studio which is very similar to your requirements.
* http://amusedia.blogspot.com/2010/11/minimize-javascript-and-css-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to determine the build configuration name. This might not be the most stable way of doing it but at least it works in the Developer Preview. It seems the string

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.folderRelativeId
```

contains the build configuration name as a substring (e.g. ".Debug."). One can then use this information at run-time to do different things base on build configuration name.

Comment: There’s at least two issues with that approach that come to mind:
1) The check is made at runtime which is very different from #define which is done at build time
2) It’s using an API in a way for which it is not intended. Indeed this approach is already broken in the consumer preview build where the value looks something like:
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.folderRelativeId "68970E9DFD4702D9\AppX" 
You should clarify your scenario, that is why do you need to pivot on this?

Comment: You are correct, it performed on run-time and as I suspected it does not work on CP. As my original question states, I need a way to determine the build configuration. Whether it's run time or build time, there is no difference.